# Trying to get Gradle to encode using UTF-8

Tags: java, gradle, encoding, utf-8, chinese-locale

I'm currently having an absolute nightmare trying to get Chinese text to display in a swing application. I'm now thinking that part of this issue may be down to my Gradle build.

I've set an environment variable `GRADLE_OPTS` to be `"-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"` as per another question but it's still reporting that the file encoding is `Cp1252`.

**In the Gradle task I'm trying to run I have the following code:**

```
println "GRADLE_OPTS: " + System.getenv("GRADLE_OPTS")
println "File encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

**This outputs:**

```
GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"
File encoding: Cp1252
```

**Later in the script I also have:**

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: I think it must be `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`, not `-file.encoding=utf-8`

Comment: @kan Yes sorry it is, I just made a typing mistake when I put it on StackOverflow; that's not the problem - it's the same issue.

Comment: Make sure your file editor saves java-files with correct encoding.

Comment: It makes more sense to use resource bundles for localised text, rather than hardcode it into source code

Comment: @kan It's not hard coded into source code, it uses resource bundles but I'm trying to ensure that the encoding is definitely correct when it's packaged into the JAR.

Comment: I pretty sure that resource files are packaged with no modifications, as is. The encoding only used by java compiler.

Comment: @kan Hi, I think you're right. I've managed to solve my issue (at least on Windows - yet to test on Linux) by changing the way my ResourceBundle getString requests works to force the returned string to be UTF-8. When ResourceBundle by default reads strings in ISO-8859-1. Thanks anyway!